# return condition if item exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select colA, colB
from tableA
where colB in ('catA','catB')
AND
colA in ('value1', 'value2', ..., 'value999')
```

Right now, this query displays a record valueX satisfies the first where condition.

How can I modify this so that the query will show ALL 999 valueX and a Yes/No column if it meets the `colB in ('catA','catB')` requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
select colA, 
       colB, 
       case when colB in ('catA','catB') 
            then 'Yes' 
            else 'No' 
        end your_column_name
  from tableA
 where colA in ('value1', 'value2', ..., 'value999') 
 order by (case colA
                when 'value1' then 1
                when 'value2' then 2
                ...
                when 'value999' then 999
            end)
```

Comment: would you happen to know if there's a way to sort the results in the order of values i put in the IN clause?

Comment: @johncs - You would need to repeat the values in the `order by` clause in the general case.  In this specific example, you could take the numeric value after the string `value` and sort by that but I assume your actual data isn't so orderly.